# Mopub: Which mediated network is serving my ads?

Tags: android, facebook, flurry, mopub, inmobi

Let's say I have integrated Mopub with Facebook Audience Network (FAN), Flurry, Inmobi. Now, I want to find out which network is actually serving the ads because maybe I want to serve Flurry's ads with a slightly different layout compared to FAN). How do I determine on my users side which ads he is seeing?

From the mopub docs : https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Native-Ads-Integration, it seems pretty linear in that we can only create one sort of layout for our native ads and we have to stick to that type of layout. What happens if for example, we want to serve videos ads from FAN and static image ads from Flurry?

Answer (score 0):

They are two separate integrations effectively - Native and banner ads. Each has a different custom events (adapter) implementation and you will need to use that appropriately.

Since the Mopub sdk and the custom event implementations are both open source, you can modify them to put in appropriate checks (or logs) to determine the ad network source. It is likely that the ad response from Mopub will contain the serving network's name (I don't recall fully as it's been a time since I mucked around in their ad response0